# mysql syntaxe is case sensitive? can I write: select, where?

Tags: mysql

can I write:

```
select * from table where id = 1
```

or should I write:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1
```

or no difference?

Comment: No difference, though I prefer the all caps (which would include FROM) style personally. Even table names are not case sensitive on most configurations.

Comment: @Uueerdo thanks! I edited to add from in caps.

Comment: Go even further and use your ticks: `SELECT * FROM \`table\` WHERE \`id\` = 1`

Comment: @Uueerdo MySQL table names are tied to their filenames on disk. If the database's filesystem is case sensitive (most Unixes) your table names will be case sensitive. If they're not (Windows, Macs) they won't be. But this is a MySQL quirk. It is ***a very bad habit*** to assume table names will be case-insensitive. It is safest to assume they are case-sensitive. This goes for most of MySQL's quirks.

Comment: @Schwern I am fairly certain MySQL has a "force case insensitive" configuration setting. ...either way, standard practice is to keep table names lower case to avoid issues that could arise transitioning between windows and `nix hosts.

Comment: Never use evil `SELECT *`. Always name (and qualify) the columns you actually want returned